# Design pattern for avoiding duplicates when paging

Tags: design-patterns

My application recieves images from users.

These images are then displayed in a grid, the grid uses the "infinite scroll" plugin, so that when the user scrolls to the bottom of the screen, the page count increments by 1 and the API returns the next set of results and appends it to the grid.

**How can I prevent duplicate records from appearing in the second set of results?**

For example if many users update the database with new images in the period between when a user loads the first and second set, the second set will be populated with many items from the first set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've three ideas.

1. Have the server remember what was sent to the client, and filter accordingly.
2. Have the client pass back the list of images currently loaded so the server can filter accordingly
3. Have the client quietly toss any duplicates received and call the server a 2<sup>nd</sup> time to get more images.

Comment: Yes all good ideas - I think number 2 is not bad actually and might be the way to go forward, which would save unncessary HTTP requests and would provide the right number of images. I think this is better than the third option as the second request might contain images from the first request, which could result in another request ad infinitum...